# Preference Screen in SlidingTabLayout

Tags: java, android, tabs, screen, preference

I am currently using the example from Google's `slidingtablayout` in my code.

I would like to replace one of the tabs' layout as a preference screen instead of the current linear/relative layout.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add item `PreferenceFragment` to your `ViewPager` adapter.

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new PrefsFragment();
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @throwaway123 from google :) [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) P.S. don't forget to accept my answer, if it was usefull :)